# spark word count using partial match

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have  a text file like this:

```
tom
and
jerry
went
to
america
and
england
```

I want to get the frequency of each word.

When I tried the following code

```
SparkConf sparkConf = new SparkConf().setMaster("local").setAppName("Word Counter");
JavaSparkContext sparkContext = new JavaSparkContext(sparkConf);
JavaRDD<String> inputFile = sparkContext.textFile("sample.txt");
JavaRDD<String> wordsFromFile = inputFile.flatMap(content -> Arrays.asList(content.split(" ")));
JavaPairRDD countData = wordsFromFile.mapToPair(t -> new Tuple2(t, 1)).reduceByKey((x, y) -> (int) x + (int) y);
countData.saveAsTextFile("CountData");
```

I got the following output

```
(england,1)
(went,1)
(america,1)
(tom,1)
(to,1)
(jerry,1)
(and,2)
```

But I need partial matches too. ie, the word `to` present in the word `tom`. So my expected word count of `to` is `2`. 
Is this calculation possible using `spark`?

Answer (score 2):

What you want to do is way more complex than the simple grouping by key. One possible solution is to start with the already counted words in `countData` and perform Cartesian product with itself using [`cartesian()`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/java/org/apache/spark/api/java/JavaRDDLike.html#cartesian-org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaRDDLike-). The result will be an RDD with elements like

```
((to,1),(tom,1))
```

For each such pair you check if the second key partially matches the first one (or vice versa) and output the key from the first pair and the value from the second. Since the Cartesian product is symmetric, processing all pairs is not strictly necessary, only pairs where the first key is lexicographically smaller than or equal to the second one:

```
((to,1),(tom,1)) -> (to,1) since to <= tom and to partially matches tom
((tom,1),(to,1)) -> (to,0) since tom > to
((to,1),(to,1))  -> (to,1) since to <= to and to (partially) matches to
```

After that mapping, you only need to perform sum reduction with `reduceByKey` and the result will be what you are looking for.

Java is not my language of choice, so I cannot give you working code, but it should be something like:

```
JavaPairRDD partialMatchData = countData
  .cartesian(countData)
  .mapToPair(t -> new Tuple2(t._1._1, partialMatch(t._1._1, t._2._1, t._2._2)))
  .reduceByKey((x, y) -> (int)x + (int)y);
```

The prototype of `partialMatch` is `(String key1, String key2, int count2)` and it returns `count2` if `key1 <= key2` else `0`.

Answer (score 1):

you will need to customize to count similar words not per line. 
proper way to do it: [Fuzzy String Matching with Levenshtein Distance and Text Similarity](https://stackabuse.com/levenshtein-distance-and-text-similarity-in-python/)

```
JavaPairRDD countData = wordsFromFile.mapToPair(t -> new Tuple2(t, 1)).reduceByKey((x, y)(int) x + (int) y);
```